# How to send HTML emails Android

Tags: java, android, html-email

I am trying to start an email intent with an HTML body but I am having trouble getting it to display on the gmail app.

```
fun sendHtmlEmail(view: View) {
        val mailId = "yourmail@gmail.com"
        val emailIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts("mailto", mailId, null))
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject text here")
        emailIntent.putExtra(
            Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
            Html.fromHtml("<html>\n" +
                    "  <body style = \\\"margin: 0; padding: 0;\\\">\n" +
                    "    <table border= \\\"1\\\" cellpadding=\\\"0\\\" cellspacing=\\\"0\\\" width=\\\"100%\\\">\n" +
                    "      <tr>\n" +
                    "        <td>\n" +
                    "          <table align=\\\"center\\\" border=\\\"1\\\" cellpadding = \\\"0\\\" cellspacing = \\\"0\\\", width = \\\"600\\\" style=\\\"border-collapse: collapse;\\\">\n" +
                    "            <tr>\n" +
                    "              <td align=\\\"center\\\" bgcolor=\\\"#70bbd9\\\" style=\\\"padding: 40px 0 30px 0;\\\">\n" +
                    "                Row 1\n" +
                    "              </td>\n" +
                    "            </tr>\n" +
                    "            <tr>\n" +
                    "                <td bgcolor=\\\"#ffffff\\\" style=\\\"padding: 40px 30px 40px 30px;\\\">\n" +
                    "                    <table border=\\\"1\\\" cellpadding=\\\"0\\\" cellspacing=\\\"0\\\" width=\\\"100%\\\">\n" +
                    "                     <tr>\n" +
                    "                      <td>\n" +
                    "                       Hello World\n" +
                    "                      </td>\n" +
                    "                     </tr>\n" +
                    "              </tr>\n" +
                    "              <tr>\n" +
                    "                <td bgcolor=\\\"#ee4c50\\\">\n" +
                    "                    Row3\n" +
                    "                </td>\n" +
                    "              </tr>\n" +
                    "          </table>\n" +
                    "        </td>\n" +
                    "      </tr>\n" +
                    "    </table>\n" +
                    "  </body>\n" +
                    "</html>")
        )
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."))
    }
```

When i run the above code I get the following email activity
[Outgoing Email Body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAHCe.png)

When I send the email to myself through a web-application, android's gmail is able to display HTML
[Proper html-email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQE6V.png)

How come it doesn't display the HTML when I'm sending the outgoing email and how come it doesn't send the HTML but only the contained words.

Comment: `Html.fromHtml()` does not support arbitrary HTML. In particular, it does not support `<table>` or related elements like `<tr>` and `<td>`. Try putting HTML [in `EXTRA_TEXT_HTML`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/content/Intent#extra_html_text) along with a plain-text representation in `EXTRA_TEXT`.

Comment: Sending the intent extra is different than receiving the extra if the email clients don't support HTML as an extra it won't work